# TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to create a list of lists using recursion in Python.

For example:

```
   li = [1,2,3,4,5] // given list

   listoflists = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5]]//required list


def recur(li,index,perlist):
    if(index==3):
       return
    else:
      templi = li[index:len(li)]
      perlist.append(templi)
      recur(li,index+1,perlist)

li = {1,2,3}
perlist = []
recur(li,0,perlist)
print perlist
```

It throws following error:

```
TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `{1,2,3}` is not a list.

Comment: {1, 2, 3} and [1, 2, 3] are two completely different objects

Comment: yeah, thanks for pointing out, it works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other users have pointed out, lists are made with [] brackets.

```
def recur(li,index,perlist):
    if(index==3):
       return
    else:
      templi = li[index:len(li)]
      perlist.append(templi)
      recur(li,index+1,perlist)

li = [1,2,3]
perlist = []
recur(li,0,perlist)
print perlist
```

works fine, giving output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]
```

The {} brackets may be a habit from some C-like language, but in Python, a list of items in {} brackets is a set (HashSet). The important distinction is that a set is unordered, and is used for membership testing, whereas a list is ordered, and supports indexing and iteration. "`has no attribute '__getitem__'`" means that a set does not support indexing. This has to do with that something like `l[0]` actually becoming `l.__getitem__(...)`. Note that {} brackets are also used for making `dict`s (HashMap, associative array..), but that's with a colon -

In more demonstrative terms:

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c = {1: "x", 2: "y", 3: "z"}
```

`a` is a set,

`b` is a list,

`c` is a dict